# Is it possible to `REVOKE` all privileges from all members from previous `GRANT`s?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Let's say I grant a privilege to "user_a", "user_b", "user_c".

Is it possible to `REVOKE` from all users in previous grants, but without specifying them explicitly? Something like this:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON "..." FROM ALL;
```

Or would I have to specify them individually?

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON "..." FROM "user_a", "user_b", "user_c";
```